# Error message display when you close the modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Goal:
Use state.firstName for displayModalContent in relation to viewing modal.

Problem:
When I opened a modal and then I want to close it, an error wil display "Cannot read property 'firstName' of null".

I don't know why this error occur and how do you solve it?

Info:
*I'm newbie in Reactjs

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qz2ywd?

Thank you!

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import Select from 'react-select';
import DisplayModalContent from './displayModalContent';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      openItem: null,
      items: [
        {
          firstName: 'Josef',
          lastName: 'Anderson',
          key: 'josef.anderson',
          startYear: 2021,
          startMonth: 2
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Jim',
          lastName: 'West',
          key: 'jim.west',
          startYear: 2020,
          startMonth: 3
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Joe',
          lastName: 'West',
          key: 'joe.west',
          startYear: 1998,
          startMonth: 10
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  handleOpenModal = openItem => {
    console.log(this.state);
    this.setState({ openItem });
  };

  handleCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ openItem: null });
  };

  handleOpenItemValue = e => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      openItem: { ...this.state.openItem, [name]: value }
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(document.getElementsByName('startMonth')[0].value);
    alert(
      JSON.stringify({
        test: document.getElementsByName('startMonth')[0].value
      })
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { items, openItem } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <table border="1">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th />
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {items.map(item => {
              const { firstName, lastName, key } = item;

              return (
                <tr key={key}>
                  <td>{firstName}</td>
                  <td>{lastName}</td>
                  <td>
                    <button onClick={() => this.handleOpenModal(item)}>
                      Open Modal
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <DisplayModalContent
          item={openItem}
          onClose={() => this.handleCloseModal()}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Modal.setAppElement(document.getElementById('root'));
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
  { value: 1, label: 'Jan' },
  { value: 2, label: 'Feb' },
  { value: 3, label: 'Mars' },
  { value: 4, label: 'April' },
  { value: 5, label: 'May' },
  { value: 6, label: 'June' },
  { value: 7, label: 'July' },
  { value: 8, label: 'August' },
  { value: 9, label: 'Sept' },
  { value: 10, label: 'Oct' },
  { value: 11, label: 'Nov' },
  { value: 12, label: 'Dec' }
];

class displayModalContent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      openItem: null,
      firstName: '',
      lastName: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(s) {
    if (JSON.stringify(this.props) !== JSON.stringify(s)) {
      this.setState({ openItem: this.props.item });
      this.setState({ firstName: this.props.item.firstName });
      this.setState({ lastName: this.props.item.lastName });
    }
  }

  handleOpenModal = openItem => {
    this.setState({ openItem });
  };

  handleCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ openItem: null });

    this.setState({ firstName: '' });

    if (this.props.onClose) {
      this.props.onClose();
    }
  };

  handleOpenItemValue = e => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;

    this.setState({
      openItem: { ...this.state.openItem, [name]: value }
    });

    this.setState({ firstName: value });
  };

  handleOpenItemValue2 = e => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;

    this.setState({
      openItem: { ...this.state.openItem, [name]: value }
    });

    this.setState({ lastName: value });
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(document.getElementsByName('startMonth')[0].value);
    alert(
      JSON.stringify({
        test: document.getElementsByName('startMonth')[0].value,
        firstName: this.state.firstName,
        lastName: this.state.lastName
      })
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { items, openItem } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {openItem !== null && (
          <Modal className="confirmation-modal" isOpen={true}>
            First Name:
            <br />
            <input
              type="text"
              id="firstName"
              name="firstName"
              value={openItem.firstName}
              onChange={e => this.handleOpenItemValue(e)}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              id="lastName"
              name="lastName"
              value={openItem.lastName}
              onChange={e => this.handleOpenItemValue2(e)}
            />
            <Select
              defaultValue={options.find(
                option => option.value === openItem.startMonth
              )}
              name="startMonth"
              id="testaaa"
              options={options}
            />
            <button onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>Close Modal</button>
            <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Test</button>
          </Modal>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default displayModalContent;
```

---

```
h1,
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.confirmation-overlay.ReactModal__Overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.confirmation-overlay.ReactModal__Overlay--after-open {
  opacity: 1;

  transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
}

.confirmation-modal.ReactModal__Content {
  position: absolute;

  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  outline: none;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.confirmation-modal.ReactModal__Content--after-open {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}

.confirmation-modal button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin: 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.confirmation-modal button:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?

Comment: Everying begins at 'this.handleCloseModal'

Comment: Right, but which line actually throws the error? EDIT: I see it now on the Stackblitz. The answer is correct as to what's happening. And the error message / stack trace lays that out for you, exactly which line caused it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the displayModalContent file where you are trying to set state in the componentDidUpdate. When you are closing the modal the componetDidUpdate will be called and at that point, the item will be null and you are trying to get a property on a null value. So either you can use componentDiDMount if you only want to set the data once on the component mounting or else you can use optional chaining([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)) so that it doesn't break the app when there is no object coming from the props.

```
componentDidUpdate(s) {
    if (JSON.stringify(this.props) !== JSON.stringify(s)) {
      this.setState({ openItem: this.props.item });
      this.setState({ firstName: this.props.item?.firstName });
      this.setState({ lastName: this.props.item?.lastName });
    }
  }
```